# Record data from get request to table in apex oracle

Tags: rest, oracle-apex

i need help with apex oracle. This task is not typical for me, so I ask for help. I have a rest point (get). As a result, I have the answer:

```html
{
  "DT_СREATE": "2020-02-05T10:38:11Z",
  "DT_UPDATE": "2020-02-05T10:38:11Z",
  "ID": 12015,
  "sensors": [
    {
      "name": "SENSOR1",
      "temp": "11.91"
    },
    {
      "name": "SENSOR2",
      "temp": "9.23"
    }
  ]
}
```

I also have a TEMPR_SILO  table. In which I want to write this answer!

```html
CREATE TABLE  "TEMPR_SILO" 
   ( "ID" NUMBER, 
 "NAME" VARCHAR2(500), 
 "TEMP" VARCHAR2(500), 
 "ID_TRANS" NUMBER, 
  CONSTRAINT "TEMPR_SILO_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
/
```

but all this should be the result of a dynamic action after pushing a button on the weed. That is, when the button is pressed, I have to record the data from the GET.
I wrote a POST for this. here he is.

```html
BEGIN 

    v_clob := iot_general.blob_to_clob(p_blob); 
    apex_json.parse(tv, v_clob); 
    v_id := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'id', p_values => tv);

    sCount := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'sensors' , p_values => tv); 
    IF sCount > 0 THEN 
      FOR i in 1 .. sCount LOOP 
        q_temp   := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'sensors['|| i ||'].temp', p_values => tv); 
        q_name := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'sensors['|| i ||'].name', p_values => tv); 

          INSERT INTO TEMPR_SILO ( NAME, TEMP,ID_TRANS)  
            VALUES ( q_name , q_temp ,v_id); 
          commit; 
          
      END LOOP; 
    END IF;
```

But I don't know how to use it in my task! I would appreciate an example or help in this question!

Comment: Hello. I just want to take a step back to get a better idea of what you're doing. You said you have a REST endpoint to get the data. Why did you create a REST endpoint to get the data? Same question for the POST... Why create a REST endpoint for that? You could, as Gabriel suggested, use Dynamic Actions with PL/SQL processes. I'm not saying what you did is wrong, it's just additional effort if it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

If you have validated that your last snippet is working, it's just a matter of creating the Dynamic Action on the button, with a PL/SQL code true action and putting it there. If you want to follow best practices, you would have that code in a procedure on the DB, and that's what you would call in the DA.

Comment: I did so, but it doesn't work https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=447720327ad555924c06437c6cf4205c